# How do I put new keywords into the 'keyword' module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before this is marked as duplicate, let me clarify. I don't want to define a new keyword. I want to put `async` and `await` into the list of keywords so they will be colored as keywords in IDLE.

Since version 3.5, `asyncio` doesn't need to be imported in order to use `async` and `await` (though there are very few circumstances where you wouldn't import `asyncio`), so I want them to be colored as keywords. I can't stand seeing `async def` where `def` is colored orange but `async` is the default black.

I looked through `colorizer.py` in `idlelib` and, while you can colorize string prefixes and the like via the module itself (I already did this for format strings) but you can't insert new keywords except by editing `keywords`. When I opened that module, I saw this:

```
    """...This file is automatically generated; please don't muck it up!

    To update the symbols in this file, 'cd' to the top directory of
    the python source tree after building the interpreter and run:

        ./python Lib/keyword.py
    """
```

I honestly don't know what is meant by "building the interpreter". Is there a way to alter this process during installation or do I have to edit the C files and run them? Or is there another, easier way?

Comment: You are free to update the file in your own installation. However, next time you build Python from source or re-install Python, that file is going to be clobbered and your manual addition will be gone again.

Comment: You would likely be better served by getting a better IDE.

Comment: The instructions are just there to remind developers working on the Python source code on how to re-generate that file manually.

Comment: As an addendum, be aware that in Python 3.7 these will be keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just update that module **dynamically**.

Create a file you store in your homedirectory with:

```
import keyword

keyword.kwlist += ['async', 'await']
keyword.iskeyword = frozenset(keyword.kwlist).__contains__
```

then set the [`IDLESTARTUP` environment variable](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/idle.html#startup) to point to that file. Now every time IDLE is started with the `-s` switch, your `keyword` module is updated to include your desired 'keywords'. If you find the `-s` switch too cumbersome, you can also move the file to `$HOME/.Idle.py` to have it loaded unconditionally, or move it to the [`USER_SITE` location](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) to run it for *all Python code*; the latter does carry more risk of course.

The warning at the top is otherwise reminding you that the file is generated when building the Python interpreter from source. If you were to edit the file now, on your system, you won't have to worry about that file being replaced. However, if you ever were to upgrade Python, it is likely to be clobbered and you'd have to make the change again.

Note that in Python 3.7, `async` and `await` *will* be actual keywords, so you won't need to wait all that long. In the meantime, you may want to pick a better IDE. I use Sublime Text 3 and Atom, both of which support the [MagicPython code highlighter](https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/), which already highlights `await` and `async` correctly.

Comment: The IDLESTARTUP variable didn't affect anything for whatever reason. I had to go to `site.USER_SITE` and put my file there. Still, I completely forgot that you could create startup files, so thank you.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold: ah, yes, because IDLE only looks at that variable when you use `-s` on the command line too, see the linked documentation. You can also use the `.Idle.py` file in your home directory.